# BeautifulSoup find() is returning none

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/BenQ-GL2580H-Monitor-Eye-Care-Reaktionszeit/dp/B073NTJHYY/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=bildschirm&qid=1597391122&sr=8-3'


headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")

print("Titel:",title,"\n","Preis:",price)
```

Output is always:
Titel: None
Preis: None

I already checked the steps before, but everything is working fine until it reaches the find function.

I never asked a question before, so forgive me if i made mistakes.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use different `parser`
try to make following changes:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

to

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```